# Individual Description (owl-api)

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I would like to add this assertion (from Protégé **"Individual Description"**) with java owl-api :

```
person hasProperty only (ClassA or ClassB )
```

As :

```
<ClassAssertion>
  <ObjectAllValuesFrom>
    <ObjectProperty IRI=“#hasProperty”/>
      <ObjectUnionOf>
        <Class IRI=“#ClassA”/>
        <Class IRI=“#ClassB”/>
       </ObjectUnionOf>
   </ObjectAllValuesFrom>
  <NamedIndividual IRI=“#Person”/>
</ClassAssertion
```

How can I do it?

```
OWLClass c1 = factory.getOWLClass(":ClassA", prefix );

OWLClass c2 = factory.getOWLClass(":ClassB", prefix );

OWLObjectProperty p = factory.getOWLObjectProperty("hasProperty", prefix);

OWLObjectIntersectionOf u = factory.getOWLObjectUnionOf(c1, c2);

OWLClassExpression e = factory.getOWLClass(property, u);

manager.addAxiom(owlOntology, factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(p, person, e));
```

Comment: `factory.getOWLClass(property, u);` <- that's clearly wrong if you look at the Javadoc of this method! use `factory.getOWLObjectAllValuesFrom(p, u)` instead.

Comment: You have the order of class name and prefix wrong. The prefix comes first. See response below.

Comment: Note: the output example that you have pasted looks like OWL/XML. If you're editing a file in place, when saving the file you do not need to specify a format, but if you're creating an ontology and do not want the default RDF/XML format you will have to specify a format argument to the `saveOntology` method.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with the code you've written:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager=OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLDataFactory factory=manager.getOWLDataFactory();
String str = "urn:test:ontology";
OWLOntology owlOntology=manager.createOntology(IRI.create(str));
String prefix=str+"#";

OWLClass c1 = factory.getOWLClass( prefix ,"ClassA");
OWLClass c2 = factory.getOWLClass( prefix, "ClassB" );
OWLObjectProperty p = factory.getOWLObjectProperty( prefix, "hasProperty");
OWLObjectUnionOf u = factory.getOWLObjectUnionOf(c1, c2);
OWLClassExpression e = factory.getOWLObjectAllValuesFrom(p, u);
OWLNamedIndividual person=factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(prefix, "Person");
manager.addAxiom(owlOntology, factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(e, person));
// don't forget to save the ontology
manager.saveOntology(owlOntology, ... output stream here...);
```

Comment: well, as mentioned in my comment below the answer, it should be `factory.getOWLObjectAllValuesFrom`

Comment: Dho! Indeed. Rushed answer.